# Are there descriptions of angels as female?

Tags: women, malach-angel

Are there any examples in tanach, talmud or midreshay chazal of an angel(s) who are described specifically as being female?

Comment: Are there examples of them being described specifically as being male?

Comment: @RonP The examples of the three "men" who came to Avraham or the one who came to Manoach. Note that he is not asking in general, but specific examples as they *can be* male, female, or neither (and not even human).

Comment: Are we talking about the malach itself, or how it appears to us? Malachim don't have genders, but when they appear in physical form they can appear in all sorts of forms, and yes, at times they have appeared female. Once this is clarified, I'll post as an answer.

Comment: @DonielF I am not asking about the malach itself, just how it is described

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Zecharia 5:9:

> וָאֶשָּׂ֨א עֵינַ֜י וָאֵ֗רֶא וְהִנֵּה֩ שְׁתַּ֨יִם נָשִׁ֤ים יֽוֹצְאוֹת֙ וְר֣וּחַ בְּכַנְפֵיהֶ֔ם וְלָהֵ֥נָּה כְנָפַ֖יִם כְּכַנְפֵ֣י הַחֲסִידָ֑ה וַתִּשֶּׂ֙אנָה֙ אֶת־הָ֣אֵיפָ֔ה בֵּ֥ין הָאָ֖רֶץ וּבֵ֥ין הַשָּׁמָֽיִם׃
>
> ‎I looked up again and saw two women come soaring with the wind in their wings—they had wings like those of a stork—and carry off the tub between earth and sky.

Translation is [Sefaria's](http://www.sefaria.org/Zechariah.5.9).